# How to make taxonomy terms link to an external site?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, redirection

I am using the [Lexicon](https://www.drupal.org/project/lexicon) module to automatically insert links to a vocabulary with information about words in the lexicon.

But the vocabularies I am using are owned and hosted by a completely different organisation, which means that hosting the information on my website would result in duplicated and outdated information. Therefore I need to link my terms in the taxonomy to an external site (instead of this website).

I tried using the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module but it doesn't manage tokens to external websites.

My question: how to make my taxonomy terms link to an external site?

Comment: After 6 hours of fighting with tokens and redirect modules I have found a very efficient solution with Field redirection module. https://www.drupal.org/project/field_redirection

I feel silly finding it 10 minutes after posting the question but I will add a good guide for other users as I've noticed that other people got similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this issue for me required three modules:

Link module: Creates a link field for external links. [Module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/link)
Lexicon: A module that look for keywords and allow you to set up a lexicon that automatically link keywords to a page explaining them. [Module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/lexicon).
Field Redirection: A module that allow you to create pages that automatically redirect the user to a different page. [Module page](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_redirection).

1. Install the modules and activate them.
2. Go to Manage fields of the vocabulary you wish to use for external links (structure-->taxonomy-->[your vocabulary]--> Manage fields). Add a link field to the vocabulary and set it's format to "redirect" (this is described in the documentation of the Field Redirection module).
3. Go to Manage display and hide all other fields (also according to FR module instructions).
4. Now it is time to set up the Vocabulary. Go to configuration-->system-->lexicon settings. Under the General tab, check "Link terms to the taxonomy term page" and uncheck the options that will make several terms appear on the same page (field redirection will otherwise always redirect to the link associated with the first term on the page).
5. Link targets are edited for each term in the taxonomy and you add the URL in the "Link" field of each term.

Lexicon is the module you interact with to make the links appear as you want them and any issues will probably be caused by improper setup of the Lexicon. Links/Redirect Field are a small add on that transport users to external websites instead of the lexicon page created by the Lexicon module.